# jquery - Numeric Only Text Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this very short clean code to only allow numeric chars in a text field.  Currently it only covers numbers 0-9 and backspace and delete.  I wanted it to also include decimal/period, so I have been fighting with this to simply include keycode 110 and/or 190.  I can not get it to work.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.numberinput').bind('keypress', function(e) { 
return ( e.which!=8 && e.which!=0 && (e.which<48 || e.which>57) ) || (e.which!=110) ? false : true ;
  });
  });
```

**jsfiddle here**: `http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/EN8pT/`

**html**

```
         <div class="label">Enter a number:</div>
        <input type="text" name="txtNumber1" id="txtNumber1" value=""  class="numberinput" />

         <div class="label">Enter a number:</div>
        <input type="text" name="txtNumber2" id="txtNumber2" value="" class="numberinput" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Why not just use `<input type="number" />`?

Comment: @Andrew Because it's an HTML5 element, therefore not supported in older browsers (namely IE8 and below, not sure about IE9).

Comment: @JamWaffles I know that, I only asked because a browser was never specified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.numberinput').bind('keypress', function (e) {
        return !(e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 &&
                (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && e.which != 46);
    });
});​
```

**JsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/EN8pT/1/

Comment: Hi Hope, no dice on this one.  The period/decimal just will not work. I created a jsfiddle here: `http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/EN8pT/`

Comment: Just ran into something similar at work - make sure to check for control/meta keys so you can still copy and paste!

Comment: @DanielLi - The above works to allow only numbers in the textbox. How to allow the enter key so that user can enter a number and hit enter to submit a form?

Answer (score 1):

With the above answer you can still do 0.23.12.33 which is not a valid number.

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/ is a great little lightweight plugin that I have used a lot.  It takes the pain out of the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#input").keydown(function(event) {
 var theEvent = event || window.event;
 var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
    if ( key == 46 || key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 27 || key == 13 ||  key == 110 || key == 190 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (key == 65 && theEvent.ctrlKey === true) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (key >= 35 && key <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (theEvent.shiftKey || (key < 48 || key > 57) && (key < 96 || key > 105 )) {
            theEvent.preventDefault(); 
        }  

    }
});
```

with keycode 110 and 190